Pandas idxmin equivalent for mean
I am trying to filter a very large dataframe that looks like this:



unique id
x
y




1
1
2


1
2
3


1
3
4


2
1
2


2
2
3


2
3
4



to only contain the mean values for each unique id, (e.g. filtered on 'x') like this:



unique id
x
y




1
2
3


2
2
3



I have tried to filter the data by doing this:
filtered_series = df.groupby("uniqueID")[some_column].mean()


Then the question is how I can filter the original dataframe based on the series above.
Now i am trying to get my original dataframe containing many rows (the same id can obviously appear many times), but with only one row per unique id.
I have tried many things, including doing an inner join like this:
df.merge(filtered_series, how="inner", on=["uniqueID", some_column])

Strangely this yielded even more rows in my df instead of filtering it.
I managed to quickly do the same task for finding the min/max value, easily achieved by the following code:
new_df = df.loc[df.groupby("uniqueID")[some_column].idxmin/max()]

Obviously there is no idxmean function, but perhaps there is a convenient way to achieve the same result.
Thank you for your help!

You know the mean isn't necessarily a sample from the data, right? e.g. the mean of 1, 2 is 1.5. This task only makes sense if it's guaranteed to be a sample, and I'm not sure why that would be. Maybe you actually want the mode? Or maybe you want the closest value to the mean?

Please write a more specific title; see [ask] for tips.

@wjandrea yes I want the closest value to the mean (i.e if sample = (1,2) I want either 1 or 2

OK, please edit to clarify that.

IIUC, you can create a new column with the difference from the mean, use idxmin on that to get the indices, then use that to filter the original dataframe:
mean = df.groupby("unique id")["x"].transform("mean")
df["diff_from_mean"] = (df["x"] - mean).abs()
idx_mean = df.groupby("unique id")["diff_from_mean"].idxmin()
df = df.loc[idx_mean].drop(columns="diff_from_mean")

   unique id  x  y
1          1  2  3
4          2  2  3


You don't need to use a temp column. You could just do diff_from_mean = mean.rsub(df['x']).abs() then idx_mean = diff_from_mean.groupby(df['unique id']).idxmin()
